# How to profile hardware in this Zenbook UX303UA failure?

Tags: debian, hardware, power-management, battery

I profiled the system with Debian installer without power supply. The laptop will shutdown after 7.5 minutes without power supply, although shown full battery. So the problem is most probably hardware, but I do not understand which part. 
I think the problem is not OS problem because I can reproduce it with live usb.

### Other details

My power average consumption is 24 W at rest (`awk '{print $1*10^-6 " W"}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now`), which should be ok. 
So there should be something else which is causing the battery die out. 
The laptop can last about 7.5 min now.

Battery details by `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` where the battery seems to be ok

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 06 Dec 2016 01:00:06 PM EET (20 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              15.664 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         22.088 Wh
    energy-full-design:  50.103 Wh
    energy-rate:         23.6529 W
    voltage:             11.31 V
    time to full:        16.3 minutes
    percentage:          70%
    capacity:            44.0852%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1481022006  70.000  charging
  History (rate):
    1481022006  23.653  charging
```

### Powertop stats

```
          Package   |             Core    |            CPU 0       CPU 2
Powered On  0.0%    | POLL        0.0%    | POLL        0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
C1E-SKL     7.4%    | C1E-SKL    14.8%    | C1E-SKL    12.6%   10.6 ms 17.1%    9.1 ms
                    |                     |
C3-SKL      0.0%    | C3-SKL      0.1%    | C3-SKL      0.1%    0.3 ms  0.1%    0.5 ms
RC6pp       0.0%    | C6-SKL      1.1%    | C6-SKL      0.0%    0.1 ms  2.2%    1.9 ms
C7s-SKL     0.0%    | C7s-SKL     0.0%    | C7s-SKL     0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
C8-SKL      9.5%    | C8-SKL     13.3%    | C8-SKL      6.7%    4.2 ms 19.9%    2.3 ms
C9-SKL      0.0%    | C9-SKL      0.0%    | C9-SKL      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
C10-SKL    76.9%    | C10-SKL    64.8%    | C10-SKL    76.1%   22.6 ms 53.3%   19.9 ms

                    |             Core    |            CPU 1       CPU 3
                    | POLL        0.0%    | POLL        0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C1E-SKL     0.0%    | C1E-SKL     0.0%    0.1 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    |                     |
                    | C3-SKL      0.0%    | C3-SKL      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C6-SKL      0.3%    | C6-SKL      0.2%    0.6 ms  0.4%    1.4 ms
                    | C7s-SKL     0.0%    | C7s-SKL     0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C8-SKL      5.6%    | C8-SKL      8.1%    6.8 ms  3.1%    2.9 ms
                    | C9-SKL      0.0%    | C9-SKL      0.0%    0.0 ms  0.0%    0.0 ms
                    | C10-SKL    88.9%    | C10-SKL    83.5%   24.1 ms 94.1%   31.7 ms

                    |             GPU     |
                    | Powered On  0.1%    |
                    | RC6        99.9%    |
                    | RC6p        0.0%    |
                    | RC6pp       0.0%    |
                    |                     |
                    |                     |
                    |                     |
                    |                     |
                    |                     |



            Package |             Core    |            CPU 0       CPU 2
Idle       100.0%   | Idle       100.0%   | Idle       100.0%      100.0%

                    |             Core    |            CPU 1       CPU 3
                    | Idle       100.0%   | Idle       100.0%      100.0%


              Usage     Device name
             13.0%        CPU core
             13.0%        DRAM
             13.0%        CPU misc
            100.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Conexant
             49.0%        Display backlight
              0.0 ops/s   GPU core
              0.0 ops/s   GPU misc
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d21
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d48
            100.0%        Radio device: asus-nb-wmi
            100.0%        Radio device: iwlwifi
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 1904
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 1916
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d31
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 1903
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d15
            100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d03
             10.3 pkts/s  Network interface: wlan0 (iwlwifi)
              0.0%        Radio device: asus-nb-wmi
              0.0%        Audio codec hwC0D2: Intel
              0.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
              0.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
              0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device 9d23
              0.0%        USB device: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam (04081-0009290016041015517)


>> Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host0                                                            
   Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host1
   Bad           Enable Audio codec power management
   Bad           NMI watchdog should be turned off
   Bad           VM writeback timeout
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d03
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d2f
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Wireless 7265
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d70
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d21
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d31
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d3a
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d48
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 1903
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 1904
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 1916
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d15
   Good          Wireless Power Saving for interface wlan0
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb1]
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb2]
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam [04081-0009290016041015517]
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Device 9d23
   Good          Wake-on-lan status for device wlan0

PowerTOP 2.6.1    Overview   Idle stats   Frequency stats   Device stats   Tunables                                     

ummary: 657.9 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 31.9% CPU use

               Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
           234.6 ms/s     331.9        Process        /usr/bin/gnome-shell
           100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: Conexant
             5.0 ms/s     116.5        Interrupt      PS/2 Touchpad / Keyboard / Mouse
             1.5 ms/s      55.3        Timer          tick_sched_timer
            40.9 ms/s      24.0        Process        /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -novtswitch -background none -noreset -verbose 3 -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-Debian-gdm-lEjDW0/database -seat
            16.2 ms/s      26.5        Process        /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
           244.6 µs/s      23.8        Process        [rcu_sched]
             0.8 ms/s      16.9        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
             5.9 ms/s      12.7        Process        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-features=BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSaverTiny,MaterialDesignUserMana
             3.6 ms/s      10.9        Process        /opt/google/chrome/chrome
           251.1 µs/s       5.7        Process        [irq/125-iwlwifi]
            53.8 µs/s       4.2        kWork          flush_to_ldisc
            13.5 µs/s       4.1        Process        nginx: worker process
            64.5 µs/s       3.2        Interrupt      [125] iwlwifi
             0.7 ms/s       2.7        Process        avahi-daemon: running [masi.local]
           272.7 µs/s       2.3        Process        /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
             2.0 ms/s       0.9        Process        powertop
            79.7 µs/s       1.5        kWork          cache_reap
            14.8 µs/s       1.5        kWork          console_callback
            69.8 µs/s       1.2        Process        syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
           422.1 µs/s       0.9        kWork          call_usermodehelper_exec_work
            21.1 µs/s       1.0        Interrupt      [126] i915
            16.8 µs/s       1.0        kWork          vmstat_shepherd
            68.3 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/sbin/acpid
           560.3 µs/s       0.7        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
             1.0 ms/s      0.26        Process        nautilus -n
             0.8 ms/s       0.5        Process        /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           201.4 µs/s       0.7        Interrupt      [1] i8042
             4.6 µs/s       0.7        Timer          sched_rt_period_timer
           221.7 µs/s       0.4        Process        nm-applet
             0.7 µs/s       0.4        kWork          blk_delay_work
            33.6 µs/s       0.3        Process        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --channel=2212.114.1220374039 --mojo-application-channel-token=E97EE6BE44BB5D48C1F
             0.6 µs/s       0.3        kWork          cfq_kick_queue
             0.8 ms/s      0.00        Process        kworker/u8:2
            64.2 µs/s      0.26        Process        [kworker/u8:2]
           142.6 µs/s      0.21        Process        /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
             1.6 µs/s      0.26        kWork          mei_timer
             3.2 µs/s      0.21        Process        /usr/bin/xprop -root -spy
             6.7 µs/s      0.21        kWork          wb_workfn
             1.6 µs/s      0.21        Process        [watchdog/3]
             1.1 µs/s      0.21        Process        [ksoftirqd/1]
           491.4 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [1] timer(softirq)
           446.0 µs/s      0.00        Process        kworker/u8:1
            51.2 µs/s      0.15        Process        /usr/sbin/minissdpd -i 0.0.0.0
            39.0 µs/s      0.15        Process        /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
            31.3 µs/s      0.15        Process        [kworker/u8:1]
             9.0 µs/s      0.15        Process        /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
             7.0 µs/s      0.15        Process        postgres: writer process
             3.7 µs/s      0.15        kWork          iwl_pcie_rx_allocator_work
             3.2 µs/s      0.15        kWork          push_to_pool
             1.8 µs/s      0.15        Process        [watchdog/1]
           385.3 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [9] RCU(softirq)
           306.4 µs/s      0.00        Timer          process_timeout
            39.9 µs/s      0.10        Process        /usr/sbin/irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid
             9.6 µs/s      0.10        Timer          watchdog_timer_fn
             4.2 µs/s      0.10        Process        runsvdir -P /etc/service log: .................................................................................................
             1.4 µs/s      0.10        Process        [watchdog/2]
             1.1 µs/s      0.10        Process        [watchdog/0]
             1.0 µs/s      0.10        Process        [ksoftirqd/0]
             1.0 µs/s      0.10        kWork          neigh_periodic_work
           173.3 µs/s      0.00        Process        /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
            28.9 µs/s      0.05        Process        /usr/lib/evolution/3.12/evolution-alarm-notify
            14.2 µs/s      0.05        Process        [jbd2/sda2-8]
           136.4 µs/s      0.00        Process        /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
             5.1 µs/s      0.05        Process        zeitgeist-datahub
             2.3 µs/s      0.05        Process        /usr/lib/packagekit/packagekitd
             1.9 µs/s      0.05        Process        /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manager
             1.8 µs/s      0.05        Process        postgres: wal writer process
             1.3 µs/s      0.05        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
             1.2 µs/s      0.05        Process        /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
             0.8 µs/s      0.05        Timer          timerfd_tmrproc
             0.6 µs/s      0.05        kWork          iwl_mvm_async_handlers_wk
             0.2 µs/s      0.05        kWork          ioc_release_fn
             0.2 µs/s      0.05        kWork          blk_timeout_work
             0.1 µs/s      0.05        Process        [ksoftirqd/2]
           113.0 µs/s      0.00        Process        /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
            86.2 µs/s      0.00        Timer          tcp_keepalive_timer
            54.4 µs/s      0.00        Timer          delayed_work_timer_fn
            29.5 µs/s      0.00        kWork          vmstat_update
            27.9 µs/s      0.00        Timer          clocksource_watchdog
            26.9 µs/s      0.00        Timer          it_real_fn
            22.1 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [4] block(softirq)
            18.8 µs/s      0.00        Process        [kworker/2:0]
            17.2 µs/s      0.00        Process        /sbin/init
            16.0 µs/s      0.00        Process        [kworker/3:0]
            11.3 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [122] ahci[0000:00:17.0]
            10.3 µs/s      0.00        Process        [kworker/1:1]
             8.7 µs/s      0.00        Process        pool
             7.7 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [6] tasklet(softirq)
             7.5 µs/s      0.00        Timer          igmp_timer_expire
             6.0 µs/s      0.00        Process        [kworker/0:1]
             5.6 µs/s      0.00        Process        [migration/1]
             4.5 µs/s      0.00        Process        [kworker/u9:0]
             3.8 µs/s      0.00        Process        [migration/3]
             3.6 µs/s      0.00        Process        [kworker/3:1H]
             1.6 µs/s      0.00        kWork          wq_barrier_func
             1.2 µs/s      0.00        Timer          commit_timeout
             1.1 µs/s      0.00        Timer          writeout_period
             1.0 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [3] net_rx(softirq)
             0.9 µs/s      0.00        Timer          blk_rq_timed_out_timer
             0.8 µs/s      0.00        Process        [migration/0]
```

OS: Debian 8.5
LK: 4.7 backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA (about 3 months old, bought from Amazon co uk as new so warranty still)

Comment: Debian 8.5 with XFCE and Chrome Open in stackoverflow and Nautilus Open no more of 5W with your awk command.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou So my value is too high. I think the too high value may indicate a battery failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DX battery failure. 
I got the computer to the service desk because the battery lasted in the end 0 seconds. 
So battery failure. 
I think the greatest indication about the thing was the test with live Linux and observing that the battery lasted only 7.5 min at one time, and lastly, 0 seconds.

Everything went to warranty. 
I think these Amazon/... discount computers have sometimes higher risk of battery failures; it would be great to get some statistics about it. 
However, it makes sense. 
If suspect defect part, sell fast out, so decrease price.

Answer (score 0):

> ... My power average consumption is 24 W at rest...

this is your starting point!
at rest my laptop consumes 3W more or less...

EDIT: in my honest opinion, you have to investigate why the laptop is so *energivorous* ; try to test the laptop with a distro using a newer kernel, because the machine is really new thus hardware can be not fully supported

Comment: So you think the awk power now command is not about the current power stage. - - There is blinking orange color in the computer. I think it is battery failure.